# error en publicacion IIS Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

estoy con el siguiente inconveniente de un sitio web asp.net core publicado en IIS.

tengo en mi sitio un elemento webcam.js que me activa la webcam cuando se entra al sitio web.
cuando publico en Azure, todo perfecto con el funcionamiento de la cámara.
Pero tengo la necesidad de publicar en IIS, y ahí estoy con algunos inconvenientes ya que la camara me sale deshabilitada.

estuve revisando y parece algo asociado al certificado SSL, pero no he logrado activar en IIS como http, y cuando le paso a https para poner el certificado no puedo acceder al sitio.

tampoco he logrado activar la cámara. Quedo atento a alguien que me pueda asesorar con este inconveniente.

Webcam.js Error: Could not access webcam: NotFoundError: The object can not be found here. NotFoundError: The object can not be found here.

Comment: ¿Con cuáles navegadores has probado? ¿Mismo comportamiento en todos?

Comment: hola Fredy, si, probe con Microsoft Edge y con Firefox, mismo problema, cuando entro a los permisos de Edge me sale deshabilitado sin opción de habilitar. 
Lo interesante es que, si publico mismo sitio en Azure App, ahí funciona perfecto en ambos navegadores.

Comment: ¿Has revisado la API de la webcam y visto si por casualidad requiere de manera obligada un https ?

Comment: he intentado con https desde IIS, pero entonces no puedo acceder al sitio desde otras pc dentro de la red.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34147315/3613462 relacionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya solucionado, tenía que habilitar el puerto nuevo para https